# ¿Cómo podría ajustar el código para completar esta multiplicación? C++

Tags: c++, array, vectores

Estoy trabajando en este programa para una clase que me pide multiplicar por 3 los valores ingresados por el usuario.

Tengo el siguiente código, pero al intentar compilarlo luego de llegar a la parte final me da el siguiente error: "*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
Aborted"

¿Cómo podría ajustarlo para que compile? Gracias de antemano.

```
int main(){
        
        float vec1[10],vec2[10];
        int n,c,b=3;
        
        cout<<"Este programa le pedirá al usuario 10 números enteros para dos vectores e imprimirá un tercer vector con la suma de los dos primeros vectores.\n";
        cout<<"--------------------------------------------------------\n";
        n=10;
        for (int c=1; c<=n; c++) {
            cout<<"Ingrese los valores de el vector: "<<endl;
            cin>>vec1[c];
        }cout<<"Limite de numeros ingresados...\n"<<endl;   
        
        for (int c=0; c<=n; c++) {
            vec2[c]=vec1[c]*b;
        }
        
        cout<<"La multiplicación de los vectores es: [";
        for (int c=1; c<=n; c++) {
            cout<<", "<<vec2[c];
        } cout<<" ]";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Intenta usar `double` en vez de `float` y dime cual es el resultado.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Me completa el vector pero no se si por alguna razon de el compilador online que uso, el ultimo valor lo expresa en notacion cientifica en vez.

Este fue el resultado: `La multiplicación de los vectores es: [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,6.25265e-309, ]`

siendo los valores ingresados de 1 hasta el 10.

Comment: No se, creo que ingresas un número muy grande y la función `cout` lo trunca.

Comment: @DanielBriceño El numero expresado en notacion cientifica es 10*3, lo cual deberia expresarlo dado que es como resultado "30" pero es extraño que ```cout``` lo trunque.

Answer (score 1):

Pues probando y ajustando me percaté que el contador no estaba en rango para que el vector recorriera de 0 hasta 9, sino hasta 10.

Luego de ajustar la constante a 9 (en vez de 10) y cambiar el iterador a 0 El bucle `for` pudo completar el recorrido y mostrar en pantalla los 10 valores digitados por el usuario multiplicado por 3.

Aqui el código corregido:

```
int main(){
        
        float vec1[10],vec2[10];
        int n,c,b=3, u;
        n=9;
        u=9;
        for (int c=0; c<=n; c++) {
            cout<<"Ingrese los valores de el vector: "<<endl;
            cin>>vec1[c];
        }cout<<"Limite de numeros ingresados...\n"<<endl;   
        
        for (int c=0; c<=u; c++) {
            vec2[c]=vec1[c]*b;
        }
        
        cout<<"La multiplicación de los vectores es: [";
        for (int c=0; c<=u; c++) {
            cout<<" "<<vec2[c];
        } cout<<" ]";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El tamaño del array no debería estar escrito a fuego sino que debería ser una constante:

```
constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
```

El motivo es que luego tienes funciones que deben conocer el tamaño del array. Si por alguna razón el tamaño del array cambia, tendrías que acordarte de actualizar todas esas funciones o el programa dejará de funcionar correctamente.

Usando expresiones constantes, te puedes desentender de ese problema:

```
float vec1[ARRAY_SIZE], vec2[ARRAY_SIZE];

for( int c=0; c<ARRAY_SIZE; c++)
    // ...
```

Si no te gusta esta solución, siempre puedes usar una plantilla para *deducir* el tamaño del array:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

Con lo cual el código quedaría así:

```
for (int c=0; c<size(vec1); c++)
```

En cualquier caso, nota que no deberías usar ni `n` ni `u`, dos variables que **siempre** deben almacenar el mismo valor para que el programa pueda funcionar.

Por otro lado, desde C++11 tenemos el for basado en rangos. Este bucle te permite iterar sobre un array de forma limpia y facil. Si junto con este for optamos por modificar `vec1` y prescindir de `vec2`, el programa quedará mucho más limpio:

```
constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
constexpr int MULTIPLICADOR = 3;
float vec1[ARRAY_SIZE];

for (float & valor : vec1)
{
    cout << "Ingrese los valores de el vector: \n";
    cin >> valor;
}

for (float & valor : vec1) {
    valor *= MULTIPLICADOR;
}
    
cout << "La multiplicación de los vectores es: [";
for (float const valor : vec1) {
    cout << " " << valor;
}
cout << " ]";
```

Si ya además calculamos la multiplicación mientras rellenamos el vector (o mientras lo mostramos... nos ahorramos un bucle:

```
constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
constexpr int MULTIPLICADOR = 3;
float vec1[ARRAY_SIZE];

for (float & valor : vec1)
{
    cout << "Ingrese los valores de el vector: \n";
    cin >> valor;
}

cout << "La multiplicación de los vectores es: [";
for (float const valor : vec1) {
    cout << " " << (valor * MULTIPLICADOR);
}
cout << " ]";
```

El for basado en rangos funciona en este caso porque el tamaño del array es conocido en tiempo de compilación. Este for no podrás usarlo con punteros, ya que en ese caso el tamaño de la reserva de memoria será un dato desconocido para el compilador.